# What are these characters notates for homogeneous coordinates?

Tags: notation

This image is captured from Needham, Visual Complex Analysis:

[image]

What are those characters called? How to type them in LaTeX? None of them appears in [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), [Variations of "z"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Variations_of_%22z%22) or [Hebrew alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fraktur $z$ ($\mathfrak{z}$, `\mathfrak{z}`) and $w$ ($\mathfrak{w}$, `\mathfrak{w}`).  Usually fraktur letters are used for ideals in commutative rings, or Lie algebras, rather than variables.

Comment: hmm, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) uses a different typeface:  and 